# Automapper projectTo generated SQL has no where clause

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

Using Entity Framework Core I'm trying to map an entity containing a child collection.
Without projectTo the generated SQL includes a where clause and only fetches the entities that belong in the child collection. When I add a projectTo, the result **is** correct but looking at the SQL I see no where clause. It appears to load all the entities of the child type and then do a where in memory.
I've tried all sorts of mappings on the collection but nothing seems to change this behavior.
Is there a way to improve this query?

The code in question is:

```
var parent = _context
                .Parents
                .Where(a => a.FamilyId == familyId && a.Id == id)
                .Include(r => r.Children)
                //.ProjectTo<ParentDetailViewModel>()
                .AsNoTracking() // In case projection contains sub entities
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

Without the project to I see the following SQL in the profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [r].[Id], [r].[FieldOne], [r].[Cid], [r].[FieldTwo], [r].[ParentId]
FROM [Child] AS [r]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP(2) 1
    FROM [Parent] AS [a]
    WHERE (([a].[FamilyId] = @__familyId_0) AND ([a].[Id] = @__id_1)) AND ([r].[ParentId] = [a].[Id]))
ORDER BY [r].[ParentId]',N'@__familyId_0 int,@__id_1 int',@__familyId_0=1,@__id_1=1
```

With project I see this. No where clause included.

```
SELECT [r].[ParentId], [r].[Id]
FROM [Child] AS [r]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently caused by an Entity Framework Core bug. Fixed in 1.1.0 preview

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule of thumb, I put the ProjectTo as the last thing before your query materialization. Put ProjectTo after AsNoTracking - HOWEVER, the AsNoTracking is pointless. With ProjectTo, you're skipping entities entirely, going straight from SQL to DTO, no entities involved at all.

Also, the Include is pointless. With ProjectTo/Select, EF knows exactly what entities it needs to join, because they're in the Select projection!

Comment: I thought Id leave in the AsNoTracking in case the DTO had sub entities that were for some reason not mapped to DTO objects. In any case commenting out both the AsNoTracking and the Include made no difference. I still see the query to fetch the children being run without a where clause